# Convert PDF to csv using ( data in single cell)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I have one pdf file which contains the data for a different person in a single cell, I wanted to process it and convert it into CSV file using python. Any help would be appreciated. Adding the screenshot for reference.

Also it would be great if it will be converted into English.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a good start...

https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/

```
import tabula

# Read pdf into list of DataFrame
df = tabula.read_pdf("test.pdf", pages='all')

# convert PDF into CSV file
tabula.convert_into("test.pdf", "output.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all')
```

Then to translate:

> pip install translate

```
from translate import Translator
translator= Translator(from_lang="arabic",to_lang="english")
for line in df:
    #translate the line instance and update the df
    translation = translator.translate(line)
```

To handle complicated PDF's here are some options to play with:

```
from tabula import read_pdf
try:
    x = read_pdf(filename, pages=pages, multiple_tables=False, error_bad_lines=False, spreadsheet=False, silent=True)
except:
    x = read_pdf(filename, encoding='latin1', pages=true, multiple_tables=False, error_bad_lines=False, spreadsheet=False, silent=True)
```

Comment: I seriously doubt that `tabula` can deal with Arabic.

Comment: It doesn't matter, pulling the data out is the primary concern, then pass the text into a translation filter after....

Comment: Thanks for the reply will check it out.. it's okay even though it won't convert into English.

Comment: Hi,  I have tried this code but did not work. Looks like this PDF has an image. Anything can we do?

Comment: Have you looked at the Tabula documentation? I added code that I use to get around most issues

Comment: Yes, I have checked it out but did not work. generating some errors. This pdf does contain the data into the image. maybe that would be creating the problem.